# Use BibDesk groups in LaTeX bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I couldn't find a reply to this anywhere, so I hope to not be asking something discussed elsewhere.

Using BibDesk (Mac OS X) for reference management, I have a single bib file with all my sources and use "Static Groups" for each project's specific references, i.e. one group for a document's reference list.

When trying the use this bib file in LaTeX, I would like to show all items in this group in the respective document's bibliography. But so far I have only been able to manually add items using \nocite{item}. Is there a way to include all items of a group without using \nocite{*}, which includes the whole bib file?

(In the bib file, the syntax for groups is "@comment{BibDesk Static Groups{ ...")

If this way does not work, what would be a simple alternative, offering one central management list from which I can easily select which references to include for which document? I would like to avoid creating a bib file for every project and like the drag-and-drop concept of BibDesk's groups.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I can't answer your question because I've never used BibDesk and have no idea what static groups are, but there is one thing you should consider doing.  When the project is over/done, you need to make a localized version of that bibliography if you want to be able to recreate the `.pdf` at a later date.  All too often, I end up catching mistakes or re-editing entries to my main bibliography file, which means certain older projects (where I didn't do this) cannot now be recreated as they were. Use `bibtool` to extract a localized bibliography, or `cp bibliography.bib projectXbibliography.bib`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You can use the "group field" menu in BibDesk (see the [official documentation](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDesk%20Help_33.html#SEC76)). It will create folders in which you can drag and drop entries at will. The data will be stored within the BibTeX entry itself. Say, if you set it to "keywords", you could then tell BibTeX to use the "keywords" field and print only the relevant entries (note: I am not sure about that, haven't used pure BibTeX in a while, but it can definitely be done in BibLaTeX).

Comment: @ienissei: I think your comment is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

You can use the "group field" menu in BibDesk (see the official documentation). It will create folders in which you can drag and drop entries at will. The data will be stored within the BibTeX entry itself. Say, if you set it to "keywords", you could then tell BibTeX to use the "keywords" field and print only the relevant entries (note: I am not sure about that, haven't used pure BibTeX in a while, but it can definitely be done in BibLaTeX).